# Trying to create many concurrent UDP flows. - java.net.SocketException Too many open files

Tags: java, udp, socketexception

I am trying to create 10000 concurrent udp flows from one computer to another using java. It works for around 3000-4000 but afterwards it gives me the following error.

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.datagramSocketCreate(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:82)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.createImpl(DatagramSocket.java:322)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:179)
    at SendThread.<init>(SendThread.java:20)
    at Client.main(Client.java:9)
```

After looking up several other links on the same error it appears that linux has a limit on how many files can be concurrently opened on a single app. That limit on my computer appears to be unlimited.

```
>ulimit 
unlimited
```

This is my code.

https://copy.com/9YwpvpScPDEUITQ8

Comment: try `ulimit -n` and updating it via `ulimit -n <some high number>`

Comment: Hi, how do I set that using Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Check `ulimit -n` and update it using `ulimit -n <some high number>`.